# Copy-SPSite for /PWA doesn't work on SharePoint 2013

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-server, project-server, cmdlets

Hello I'm trying to make a script to move an `ProjectServer` site from one farm to another.
To to this, first I import the `WSS_Content` database then try to rename the `/PWA` site with Copy-SPSite powershell cmdlet. Then I mount the project server databases and do other work.

The problem is when I try to copy the `/PWA` site to `/PWAExample` it creates another `/` site that doesn't work. If I run `Test-SPSite http://domain/` it gives me this huge error.
The `Copy-SPSite http://domain/sites/old -targetUrl http://domain/sites/new` works. It dosent work with `Copy-SPSite http://domain/PWA -targetUrl http://domain/PWAExample`

```
    test-spsite : SPSiteHealthChecker: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException exception thrown in SPSiteHealthChecker.Test():
 <nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.OpenWebInternal(String bstrUrl, Guid& pguidID, DateTime& pdtTimeCreated, String& pbstrRequestAccessEmail, UInt32& pwebVersion, String& pbstrServerRelativeUrl, UInt32& pnLanguage, UInt32& pnLocale, String& pbstrDefaultTheme, String& pbstrDefaultThemeCSSUrl, String& pbstrThemedCssFolderUrl, String& pbstrAlternateCSSUrl, String& pbstrCustomizedCssFileList, String& pbstrCustomJSUrl, String& pbstrAlternateHeaderUrl, String& pbstrMasterUrl, String& pbstrCustomMasterUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoDescription, Object& pvarUser, Boolean& pvarIsAuditor, Int32& plSiteFlags, Boolean& pbOverwriteMUICultures, Boolean& pbMUIEnabled, String& pbstrAlternateMUICultures, Int32& plSiteSchemaMajorVersion, Int32& plSiteSchemaMinorVersion, Int32& plSiteSchemaBuildVersion, Int32& plSiteSchemaRevisionVersion, Int32& puiVersion, Int16& pnClientTag, Boolean& pfIsEvalSite, Guid& pgSourceSiteId, DateTime& pdtExpirationDate, Guid& pgEvalSiteId, Guid& pguidAppInstanceId, String& pbstrRemoteAppUrl, String& pbstrOAuthAppId, String& pbstrAppDatabaseName, Guid& pgAppDatabaseServerReferenceId, String& pbstrAppDatabaseTargetApplicationId, String& pbstrAppWebDomainId, Int32& plUpgradeFlags, DateTime& pdtReminderDate, DateTime& pdtLastContentChange, DateTime& pdtLastSecurityChange, UInt64& pmaskDeny)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.OpenWebInternal(String bstrUrl, Guid& pguidID, DateTime& pdtTimeCreated, String& pbstrRequestAccessEmail, UInt32& pwebVersion, String& pbstrServerRelativeUrl, UInt32& pnLanguage, UInt32& pnLocale, String& pbstrDefaultTheme, String& pbstrDefaultThemeCSSUrl, String& pbstrThemedCssFolderUrl, String& pbstrAlternateCSSUrl, String& pbstrCustomizedCssFileList, String& pbstrCustomJSUrl, String& pbstrAlternateHeaderUrl, String& pbstrMasterUrl, String& pbstrCustomMasterUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoUrl, String& pbstrSiteLogoDescription, Object& pvarUser, Boolean& pvarIsAuditor, Int32& plSiteFlags, Boolean& pbOverwriteMUICultures, Boolean& pbMUIEnabled, String& pbstrAlternateMUICultures, Int32& plSiteSchemaMajorVersion, Int32& plSiteSchemaMinorVersion, Int32& plSiteSchemaBuildVersion, Int32& plSiteSchemaRevisionVersion, Int32& puiVersion, Int16& pnClientTag, Boolean& pfIsEvalSite, Guid& pgSourceSiteId, DateTime& pdtExpirationDate, Guid& pgEvalSiteId, Guid& pguidAppInstanceId, String& pbstrRemoteAppUrl, String& pbstrOAuthAppId, String& pbstrAppDatabaseName, Guid& pgAppDatabaseServerReferenceId, String& pbstrAppDatabaseTargetApplicationId, String& pbstrAppWebDomainId, Int32& plUpgradeFlags, DateTime& pdtReminderDate, DateTime& pdtLastContentChange, DateTime& pdtLastSecurityChange, UInt64& pmaskDeny)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitWebPublic()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_Language()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SiteHealth.SPSiteHealthConflictingContentTypeRule.ProcessWeb(SPWeb spWeb)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SiteHealth.SPSiteHealthRule.ProcessWebs(SPWeb spWeb)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SiteHealth.SPSiteHealthRule.ProcessWebs(Boolean repair)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SiteHealth.SPSiteHealthConflictingContentTypeRule.Test()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SiteHealth.SPSiteHealthChecker.Test(Guid _ruleId, Boolean _repair, Boolean _runAlways, SPLongOperationState longOperation,
String statusFormat)
 SPSite="http://domain"
 ruleId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
 repair=False
 CompatibilityLevel=15
At line:1 char:1
+ test-spsite http://domain/
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...PCmdletTestSite:SPCmdletTestSite) [Test-SPSite], SPSiteHealthCheckerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletTestSite
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that /PWA is actualy a managed path. And copy a site collection to new managed path you first have to create it with `Explicit inclusion`.